# React router render prop route always re-renders components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using React Router and because a function that takes a components needs need to be passed into the route, am rendering the components with a render prop. However, passing in a route as a render prop always results in the component re-rendering. I have tried all the possible lifeCycle hooks, such as shouldComponentUpdate and ComponentDidUpdate, but nothing prevents the component from re-rendering. This route structure is shown below:

Route1:

```
<Route
  path='/dashboard'
  render={() => dashboardOperator(<Dashboard />)}
/>
```

Conversely, if I just pass the component in the traditional way, it does not trigger an automatic re-render.

Route2:

```
 <Route
     path="/dashboard"
     component={DashboardComponent}
 />
```

However, this routing approach is not effective because it does not allow the function to be passed into the route.

Since lifecycle hooks do not appear to be effective in preventing Route1 (the render prop approach) from re-rendering the component, how can I use the render prop (or another approach) and also prevent unnecessary component re-renders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  renderDashboardPage() {
    return dashboardOperator(<Dashboard />)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Route
        path='/dashboard'
        render={this.renderDashboardPage}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

This should work because the function/object reference stays the same across re-renders, so React will realize the props have not changed. Although, be careful about pre-mature optimization.

Comment: that worked. i'm confused what you mean the function/object reference staying the same. basically before, since a function was passed in that wasn't part of the containing class it automatically triggered the re-render?

Comment: By using an inline function (`render={() => dashboardOperator(<Dashboard />)}`) , you're creating a new function every time the parent component renders. React compares the old function to the new function, see's they're different, and re-renders. By using the approach I detail in my answer, you only create the function once, which means React can tell it's the same function.

Comment: If anybody still stumble upon this, this also works (if you wanna go inline): ```render={function siskebab(props) {return <Dashboard variable={kebab} />}```